# Is it possible to make system software (not web application) in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to ruby on rails and I have a confusion that is it possible to make the software(application software) in ruby on rails that is not a web application that can be install into computer and use it.

Actually I was thinking to develop an application that can be install on a pc and can be use offline. Lets take an example grocery shop management.

Comment: Rails is a framework to make web applications, so if you do not want a web application but a desktop application, it will provide you with a lot of stuff you don't want or need...

Comment: This is not opinion based, as one voter thought, but it is a bit unclear.  Can you please edit the question to explain what you mean by "system software?"  Perhaps you can describe the application you have in mind, and explain how it would be used.  Would someone invoke it in the console?  Would it have a GUI window on their desktop?  Is it run as a background task by the operating system?

Comment: Actually I was thinking to develop an application that can install on pc and can be use offline. Lets take an example grocery shop management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails is a web framework, and it needs a browser to be used. It looks like you might be looking for something like [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/).